Black bubble reaction with Hydrogen Peroxide and potatoes; Triiodine and starch reaction?
In biology, we were doing an experiment mixing 15ml of hydrogen peroxide with 4 slices of potato in a graduated cylinder. In 5/6 tests the reaction created clear bubbles. this is the hydrogen peroxide and catalase reaction, but in the last reaction, I added the hydrogen peroxide to the graduated cylinder, and a yellow liquid formed. When we added the potato the reaction created bubbles, but the solution turned black what could this be? The only thing I found it could have been was an iodine and hydrogen peroxide reaction removing the O2 from the peroxide and creating triiodine. I'm confused about how there was still a bubble reaction if the O2 was removed from the peroxide because the peroxide is no longer peroxide but water.
Something to note is that it was not an elephant toothpaste reaction it was a bubble reaction over 10 min.

Do you iodine or an extra reactant in your mixture or?
